# Split a column into three columns using two different characters as separators

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, pattern-matching

Using PostgreSQL, I'd like to split the values appearing in one of the columns in my table according to TWO (not one) character. My column `id2` includes values such as:

```
chr1:10000485-10006485@NM_022787@NMNAT1
```

I would like to split the column into three columns accordingly (using both, the ":" and the "-" characters as separators:

```
chr1  |  10000485  | 10006485@NM_022787@NMNAT1
```

Currently my code is:

```
select split_part(id2, ':', 1)s1,split_part(id2, ':', 2) s2, id2
from MyTable
```

This outputs as follows (two columns where s1 and s2 are the headers):

```
s1    |     s2
chr1  |  10000485-10006485@NM_022787@NMNAT1
```

How can I split `id2` based on both, ":" AND "-"? 
can I somehow do sequential split using `s2`?

I tried using:

```
select split_part(id2, ':', 1)s1,split_part(id2, ':', 2) s2, split_part(s2, '-', 2)
```

But got the error message:

> ```
> ERROR:  column "s2" does not exist
> LINE 7: ... ':', 1)s1,split_part(id2, ':', 2) s2, split_part(s2, '-', 2...
>                                                              ^
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: column "s2" does not exist
> SQL state: 42703
> Character: 160
> ```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider [markdown formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a 'with' query like so:

```
With q1 as (
   select split_part(id2, ':', 1) s1, split_part(id2, ':', 2) s2, id2
   from MyTable
   )
select s1, s2, split_part(s2, '-', 3) s3
from q1;
```

Answering from phone for the first time. I will correct later.

Comment: For the record: a CTE achieves the same as a subquery in this case, just a bit more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

One way is with `regexp_split_to_table()`

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_table(id2, '[:-]')
FROM  (VALUES ('chr1:10000485-10006485@NM_022787@NMNAT1')) tbl(id2)
```

Results in multiple rows:

```
regexp_split_to_table
----------------------
chr1
10000485
10006485@NM_022787@NMNAT1
```

Or with `regexp_split_to_array()`:

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_array(id2, '[:-]')
```

Which you can then access:

```
SELECT arr[1] AS s1, arr[2] AS s2, arr[3] AS s3 --, ...
FROM (
    SELECT regexp_split_to_array(id2, '[:-]') AS arr
    FROM  (VALUES ('chr1:10000485-10006485@NM_022787@NMNAT1')) tbl(id2)
    ) sub;

s1      s2          s3
--------------------------------------------
chr1    10000485    10006485@NM_022787@NMNAT1
```

Or nest `split_part()` - and add all input columns to the right, as requested in the comment:

```
SELECT split_part(id2, ':', 1) AS s1
      ,split_part(split_part(id2, ':', 2), '-', 1) AS s2
      ,split_part(split_part(id2, ':', 2), '-', 2) AS s3
      ,*
FROM  (VALUES ('chr1:10000485-10006485@NM_022787@NMNAT1')) tbl(id2);
```

Same result (plus all input columns). It really depends on how your strings can vary.

#### Explain error

The error you get results from the fact that you can only reference *input* columns in the SELECT list, not *output* columns.
You would need to wrap the query in a *subquery* to reference output columns (`s2` in your case), or *repeat* the expression based on input columns, like demonstrated above.

Comment: To be more precise 
I'd like to create query that conjugates the new 3 splits to the very left of my original table. 
If I split my column based on one character, for example ":", this would be as following:

select split_part(id2, ':', 1)s1,split_part(id2, ':', 2) s2, * 
from roynewtable

I enjoy in this query the use of the star (*) which allows me to output my entire original table as is, without actually denoting each and every column (I have 15 columns in my table...) 
Can I perform split on 2 different characters and still use * in my SELECT to avoid designation of each column?

Comment: @Roy: `*` is just short-hand for "all input columns" and can be used in every `SELECT`. This is a fundamental basic of SQL.

Comment: Yes, of course (I know that) - yet, and I don't have the exact query i tired earlier this evening - but at some point when i tried SELECT *, as opposed to SELECT explicit columns - I have received the entire table columns (= *) - being output as one column(!). Meaning, the entire table's columns where output as one column, with no separation...When I designated column by column however, my output was back to normal...  I'll try to retrieve my attempts to show you if I'll find it!....

Comment: as a matter of fact - after taking in account all the good comments here (Thanks guys!) - my final and simplest solution (i think..) is this: select split_part(s2, '-', 1)s3,*
from
(select split_part(id2, ':', 1)s1,split_part(id2, ':', 2) s2, * 
from roynewtable)t2

Comment: You realize that your `s2` consists of the 2nd *and* 3rd part, right? As for "whole row as single column": you can get that with `SELECT t FROM roynewtable t`. It is the text representation of the composite row type.

Comment: yes, yes, of course. at the end of the procedure (next step) - i simply do ORDER BY and designating column s1 and s3. (i actually do a prior join with a small table of chromosomeName,ChromosomeNum (for example - chr1,1; chrX,24. Then I can sort everything based on chromosomeNum and s3. 

As it goes to the text representation of the composite row type - YES! this is exactly what I've got - you got it right! :) TNX!
I must have done something similar instead of using the star (*)

Btw, what the best way to remove column(s) from a table? thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Roy: Start a new question for a new question. Or, if it is that simple, read the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html). Comments are not the place.